# Can't delete session value in laravel5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use these codes to stop multiple form submission.But it doesn't work. I found 
**$form_token** and **$token** were always the same. I had writted session(['form_token' => null]). But It doesn't work.Why?

```
// make token
function form_token()
{
    session(['form_token' => Str::random(40)]);
    return session('form_token');
}

//check token
function check_token($form_token, $token)
{
    if ($form_token == $token) {
        session(['form_token' => null]);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException('Do not submit multiple times');
    }
}

// middleware
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!in_array($request->method(), ['HEAD', 'GET', 'OPTIONS'])) {
        $form_token = $request->input('form_token');
        $token      = session('form_token');
        check_token($form_token, $token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`forget()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#deleting-data) method:

```
session()->forget('form_token');
```

Comment: When I add "sleep(3)" in the controller store function, this problem happened. When I delete "sleep(3)", it seems to work.